# webapp in python

Tags: python, dns

I have got a very simple idea in mind that i want to try out. Say i have a browser, chrome for instance, and i want to search for the ip of the domain name, say `www.google.com`. I use windows 7 and i have set the dns lookup properties to manual and have given the address `127.0.0.1` where my server (written in Python is running). I started my server and i could see the dns query but it was very weird as in it is showing faces like this:

```
WAITING FOR CONNECTION.........

.........recieved from :  ('127.0.0.1', 59339)

╟╝☺  ☺      ♥www♠google♥com  ☺ ☺
```

The `waiting for connection` and the `received from` is from my server. How do i get a human readable dns query?

This is my server code(quiet elementary but still):

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep 
import socket 
host='' 
port=53 
addr_list=(host,port) 
buf_siz=1024 
udp=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
udp.bind(addr_list) 
while True: 
    print 'WAITING FOR CONNECTION.........' 
    data,addr = udp.recvfrom(buf_siz) print '.........recieved from : ',addr 
    sleep(3) 
    print data
```

Comment: I fixed you post for you. Next time, use some more punctuation, and don't do the multiple question-mark thing. Also, could you post the code from your server that receives this query?

Comment: post your code please...reading binary on a terminal?

Comment: thx for tat..will keep in mind

Comment: @Preetam: Please don't post code in comments. You can edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

DNS uses a compression algorithm and uses [length]string to represent parts of the domain name (as far as I remember).  e.g. [3]www[6]google[3]com.

Have a look at the DNS RFCs, e.g. http://www.zoneedit.com/doc/rfc/rfc1035.txt